# Animation on submit event

Tags: html, css

[check code](https://drive.google.com/open?id=13TmCcoTEO89Pk8sbngJGwnvMXf8uy5b5)
I have share one picture of my website login page below and I want  zoom text animation on hover for "Sign In" button which is    ...

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    background-image:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(19,20,25,0.8), rgba(19,20,25,0.8)), url('../images/barbell-on-the-floor-1552252.jpg');
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}


.form{
    position: relative;
    width: 350px;
    padding: 40px 60px;
    background-color: #131419;
    border-radius: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: -3px -3px 20px rgba(33, 150, 243,0.5),
                 10px 10px 10px rgba(33, 150, 243, 0.05);

}

.form h2{
    color: #c7c7c7;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 4px;

}

.form .input{
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.form .input .inputbox{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.form .input .inputbox label{
    display: block;
    color: #868686;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.form .input .inputbox input{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #131419;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 40px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #03a9f4;
    box-shadow: inset -2px -2px 6px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1),
                inset  2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.form .input .inputbox input[type="submit"]{
    margin-top: 20px;
    box-shadow:  -2px -2px 6px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1),
                  2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.form .input .inputbox input[type="submit"]:active{
    color: #006c9c;
    margin-top: 20px;
    box-shadow: inset -2px -2px 6px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1),
                inset  2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);

}

.form .input .inputbox input::placeholder{
    color: #555;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.create{
    color:grey;
    margin-top: 30px;
    font-weight: lighter;
}

.create a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #03a9f4;
    font-size: 80%;
}

.forget{
    color:grey;
    margin-top: 15px;
    font-weight: lighter;
}

.forget a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #03a9f4;
    font-size: 80%;
}

.inputbtn{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    
}

.inputbtn input{
    color: #2196f3;
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    border-color: #2196f3;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline: none;
}

.inputbtn input:hover{
    color:#255784;
    background: #2196f3;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #2196f3, 0 0 40px #2196f3, 0 0 80px #2196f3;
    text-transform: scale(0.20)    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="This website is for workout lovers and Here you can get knowledge about workout and nutrition">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="./images/dumbbell-pixel-variant (1).png" type="image/png">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,400;1,100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Workout</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="form">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <div class="input">
            <div class="inputbox">
                <label>Username</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="example@gmail.com">
            </div>
            <div class="inputbox">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="••••••••">
            </div>
            <div class="inputbtn" id="submit">
            <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Sign In">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="create">
            <p>or Create Account <a href="#">Click Here</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="forget">
            <p>Forget Password ? <a href="#">Click Here</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

check Image:
[image: check Image]

Comment: It's a simple solution but please add a sample of your code so we can test here

Comment: Hello Hritik, welcome to StackOverflow! It helps people to help you if you share what you already tried to make it work. As for the answer - I'll say look into the :hover and box-shadow css properties, and you will have your answer. :)

Comment: You must include the code in the question not on Drive. We need to see [mcve] if you want us to help you fix the issue.

Comment: @Ivan86 i have shared code link you check now.....

Comment: @HritikPotawade what happened to the comments below my answer and out of curiosity why did you change the accepted answer?

Comment: @Ivan86 oh sorry that was my mistake......

Comment: @Ivan86 I hope you understand me.....

Comment: @Ivan86 i have one more question for you

Comment: @Ivan86 i visited this "https://glenncatteeuw.com/" website yesterday and i want to know how i can create that on hover menu effect..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you described, I believe this is what you want. I've added `font-weight:bold;` and `font-size: 1.4em;` to the `.inputbtn input:hover{}` CSS instruction.

This might not be the exact amount text zooming that you wanted but you can easily configure it as you wish.

**Run and test:**

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    background-image:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(19,20,25,0.8), rgba(19,20,25,0.8)), url('../images/barbell-on-the-floor-1552252.jpg');
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}


.form{
    position: relative;
    width: 350px;
    padding: 40px 60px;
    background-color: #131419;
    border-radius: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: -3px -3px 20px rgba(33, 150, 243,0.5),
                 10px 10px 10px rgba(33, 150, 243, 0.05);

}

.form h2{
    color: #c7c7c7;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 4px;

}

.form .input{
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.form .input .inputbox{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.form .input .inputbox label{
    display: block;
    color: #868686;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.form .input .inputbox input{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #131419;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 40px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #03a9f4;
    box-shadow: inset -2px -2px 6px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1),
                inset  2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.form .input .inputbox input[type="submit"]{
    margin-top: 20px;
    box-shadow:  -2px -2px 6px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1),
                  2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.form .input .inputbox input[type="submit"]:active{
    color: #006c9c;
    margin-top: 20px;
    box-shadow: inset -2px -2px 6px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1),
                inset  2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);

}

.form .input .inputbox input::placeholder{
    color: #555;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.create{
    color:grey;
    margin-top: 30px;
    font-weight: lighter;
}

.create a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #03a9f4;
    font-size: 80%;
}

.forget{
    color:grey;
    margin-top: 15px;
    font-weight: lighter;
}

.forget a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #03a9f4;
    font-size: 80%;
}

.inputbtn{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    
}

.inputbtn input{
    color: #2196f3;
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    border-color: #2196f3;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline: none;
}

.inputbtn input:hover{
    color:#255784;
    background: #2196f3;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #2196f3, 0 0 40px #2196f3, 0 0 80px #2196f3;
    text-transform: scale(0.20);
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size: 1.4em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="This website is for workout lovers and Here you can get knowledge about workout and nutrition">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="./images/dumbbell-pixel-variant (1).png" type="image/png">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,400;1,100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Workout</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="form">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <div class="input">
            <div class="inputbox">
                <label>Username</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="example@gmail.com">
            </div>
            <div class="inputbox">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="••••••••">
            </div>
            <div class="inputbtn" id="submit">
            <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Sign In">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="create">
            <p>or Create Account <a href="#">Click Here</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="forget">
            <p>Forget Password ? <a href="#">Click Here</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try something along the lines of ':placeholder:hover' in order to target the selector which lets you hover over the element and will affect the text within the placeholder. After that you could try to put the 'transition' property within the curly braces - {} - and set the 'font-size' property for the text size you desire. On theory it should adjust the font size to the value you've set whenever you hover your cursor over the placeholder.